# <!-- in a <style> declaration - What are it's different uses and meanings?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commenting out stylesheets in HTML documents to support older browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825773/commenting-out-stylesheets-in-html-documents-to-support-older-browsers)

I'm trying to understand the purpose for the comment when doing certain types of styling.  I have seen it before in instances of IE conditional styling.

Here is one I saw this morning:

```
<style tyle="text/css">
<!--
@page { size:8.5in 11in; margin: 2cm }
-->
</style>
```

**What purpose does this serve here, and also when is the other uses for this, and when are they appropriate.  Does CSS not read the comment, or does it mean something completely different in CSS?**

Comment: thanks.  Could not get this to show up in search.  This question is worded better for people searching, where as the link has the answer in the question and may not come up how people will search for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a HTML comment as intended to ensure backwards compatible with "ancient browsers" that don't support CSS.

Don't bother with it!

Comment: And the browser reads it the same with or without the comment...  So when it was used originally it was for the purpose of a browser that couldn't understand CSS?

Answer (score 3):

It's just a comment and is meant for backwards compatibility with ancient browsers. It's not really needed nowadays as modern browsers support CSS just fine even if they don't necessarily support all of its features.